# Spring Boot best practices for hiding or encrypting passwords

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been using the Spring Framework for about 4 years now, and now Spring Boot for the last couple of months. My Spring MVC applications are usually deployed on a Java EE container such as JBoss/WildFly or WebLogic. Doing so allows me to use JNDI for things like datasources or any other sensitive data that involve secrets/passwords. That makes my app "consume" that JNDI resource based on its name.

Now with Spring Boot and especially for self-contained microservices (embedded tomcat), that information is now stored within the application (application.properties and/or in Spring Java Config classes), so versioned in Git.

That makes that information a lot more exposed to other developers, which I'm not very comfortable with. I also don't like having those details show up in SonarQube and Jenkins (through workspaces).

Question is: Are there any best practices for this specific requirement?

*** UPDATE ***
I see some articles here and there about the use of Jasypt, but I wonder if it's still a valid library to use since the last stable release is dated from 2014.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a vault. Spring supports a few of them out of the box. You can find more information here http://projects.spring.io/spring-vault/.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spring cloud in your stack, then it's very easy. Use encrypt the value and put it in the application properties. Follow the instruction mentioned [here](https://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/encrypted-properties-spring/).

Other way is, set the values as environmental variables and using the environmental variables in the application properties. Instructions [here](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/using-environment-variables-with-spring-boot/)